# Why does type(object) return <class 'type'> instead of <class 'object'>?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was playing around in REPL and noticed behavior regarding the built-in `object` base class that confuses me:

```
>>> object
<class 'object'>
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
```

Why is the type of `object` in this case not `<class 'object'>`? What's happening here?

Comment: `object` is a type. `type` returns the type of its argument, not the type of instances of its argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes are always, directly (implicit in all classes without a declared metaclass) or indirectly (via metaclasses, which are always subclasses of `type`), instances of `type`. `object` itself is a class, you didn't make an instance of it, so it can't report itself to be an instance of `object` (not directly anyway; `isinstance(object, object)` does return `True`, because everything, including `type` itself, is an instance of `object` if you follow the inheritance chain far enough).

If you'd made an instance of `object`, e.g. `type(object())`, it would report what you expected.